# What is the easiest way to make money?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

What's the most efficient way to farm Pokemon Dollars/money in Pokemon X & Y? I'd love to be able to have a decently sized wallet so I can show it off to others, but mainly to buy tons of Max Repels when venturing through the wild.

I remember how hard it would be in previous Generations.  For example, in Gen V, I remember repeatedly grinding the Elite Four just to make some serious profit, but it took hours of grinding to reach a decently sized wallet.

What's the most efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fastest way to get money is Le Wow. But, it does cost 100K to attempt. I built a strategy to do it.

First, you need 2 high level Pokemon (70 or higher), preferably ones who can use moves like earthquake or surf ( I use Charizard and Flygon). Make sure they also have a stalling move (Like fly or a stat raiser) so you can be more precise with the turns completing.

Secondly, you need an amulet coin (for increased money earning) and prize money O-Power (level 3 preferably) or a friend who can use it.

Now, have your two high levels in slot 1 and 2 of your party. Make sure one has the amulet coin. Walk into Le Wow and use the Prize Money O-Power. Then talk to the lady. Choose the double battle and pay her 100K (Can be lowered, not sure how). Now, you go through a series double battles. Each double battle gives prize money ( and good EXP for leveling Pokemon). Try to win the battles in the target time stated for more end money. Once all of the battles are over, you are rewarded Balm Mushrooms, which go for 6K each. If you get all of the battles in the correct amount of turns ( and none of your Pokemon fainting), you get 25 Balm Mushrooms.

25 * 6000 = 150000 Poke, which is more than you had to pay to enter. Also, you get 10K for the first 2 battles (Without Amulet Coin) and 4K for the last 3 battles (Without Amulet Coin).

150000 + (20000 * 2) + (8000 * 3) = 24000 + 40000 + 150000 = 214000 Poke per run. That did not include the Prize Money O-Power, but it did include the Amulet Coin.

214000 - 100000 (Fee to enter) = 114000 Poke profited per run, if everything goes right.

If you do not have 100K Poke to enter Le Wow, you can do Elite Four runs. With Amulet Coin + Prize Money O-Power and/or the Battle Chateau to earn 100K easily. Also, if you are lucky, the people you beat at the Battle Chateau might give you selling items, like pearls and nuggets.

Both the Elite Four and Le Wow give lots of profits, but Le Wow is much easier seeing that your opponents only have 2 Pokemon in double battles (3 in triple and rotation), and are always level 63. Also, unlike the Elite Four, the people in Le Wow do not use full restores.

EDIT: With the new Event Inkay (with a move called Happy Hour) you can make EVEN more money. But, as of now, it is a Japanese only event. The move increases the money earned from battles.

EDIT: If you throw in PayDay, you can get EVEN more money. PayDay takes the level of the user, multiplies it by 5 (in gen 3 or higher) and scatters coins of those value. AND, it is effected by Amulet Coin (Pokebank will allow you to move a Meowth/Persian up to X and Y). And then at the end of the battle, you pick the money and it is added to your amount.

EDIT: If you complete the Le Wow challenge perfectly at least once, the cost for it lowers.

EDIT: If you use Amulet Coin + Prize Money O-Power 3, and have the discount, you earn a total of 150000 + (60000 * 2) + (24000 * 3) - 90000 = 252000 per run, plus lots of EXP.

Comment: The price of entry to the restaurants can be lowered by taking the exact amount of 'recommended' turns for each meal. At the end they'll say something about you being quite the fine diner, waiting until the meal is 'perfect' to start eating. Buying the same meal next time, it will have a star next to it, and will cost $90k instead of $100k

Answer (score 1):

I've literally been going to the Battle Chateau until no one new shows up and then going to the Elite Four. The more people you beat at the chateau usually causes people willing to dish out more money to appear and even if they don't you can get 6-14k per battle against a single level 20 or so. (I give the first Pokemon in my party a luck incense that I bought at the incense store in  to double the reward money there and at the e4.

Also as mentioned getting the prize money O-power and receiving it from friends yields incredibly high rewards from battles.

Comment: Don't forget the Prize Money O-Power.

Comment: Yeah the prize money O Power level 3 seems to triple battle earnings. With an Amulet coin I got 98k or so from the Champ and 78 from the E4 members.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on playing a lot over the course of the day, an investment in the Battle Chateau can really pay off.  Buy the Gold Writ of Invitation (available for 100,000, starting at rank Earl), and all prize money you receive there will be increased by 50% until Midnight.  Combine that with the Prize Money O-Power, and an Amulet Coin equipped to your primary pokémon, and you'll be rolling in the money quickly.

Comment: You should also get a Silver Writ. It makes new guys appear pretty much after every single battle you do.

Answer (score 0):

The most money you can possibly get per battle right now is by using Prize Money Power lv.3 while holding an amulet coin. You can go to the Pokemon League and beat them repeatedly while using the o-power and the amulet coin, you'll get about 96,000 per E4 member and about 200,000 for the champion. That totals out to upwards of 500,000 dollars per run. But once the Pokemon Bank comes out, you can get a little more if you have a lv.100 Persian or Meowth with Pay Day. Not only is technician Pay Day from Persian a decent move, but it'll get you a small boost in funds, about 400 per battle. Therefore you can get an additional 2,000 per run. Not much more but a little bit more. Hope this helps.

HAPPY GRINDING!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to restaurant Le Yeah and select 1 of the 2 battle types and they will begin battling you.(Also the last one sounds like it will kill you if you eat it)You will receive 4,960 dollars (If your Pokemon in the front of your party is holding the amulet coin you will receive 9,920  dollars)from the owner. Almost what you paid for.Their pokemon will be at lvl.31 So have pretty bulky pokemon. Then at the end of all of it sell the big mushrooms and make big bucks by doing it a bunch of times(No o-power required).HOPE THIS HELPED =)