# Money cheats for Pokemon X?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Money cheats on Pokemon X anyone, because I want to get the thing that the guy offers for 1,000,000 poke-dollars in the main city. By the way, where is that guy in the main city offering that thing anyway, and what is it?

Comment: I *heavily* recommend you stop asking questions surrounded by double or triple asterisks.  They don't help at all.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no money 'cheats'. [However, there are several ways to increase the amount you earn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157013/early-money-making-strategies?rq=1). The NPC you are looking for is in the [Stone Emporium](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stone_Emporium#Stone_Emporium), he is selling one of the Mega Evolution Stones, but keep in mind that the price decreases to a minimum 10,000 poke-dollars once you reach maximum [stylishness](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lumiose_City#Style).

Answer (score 0):

There are no Money Cheats in Pokemon X and Y, Though there are some really effective ways to gain money in the game.

The best method is:

- Get a Level 100 Pokemon, (Preferably one with a ton of attack, I usually use Dragonite)
- Get an amulet coin
- Give Dragonite the Amulet Coin
- Max out the prize money O-Power
- Go to the elites with your Dragonite holding the amulet coin and before each battle use the maximum Prize Money O-Power, After each battle you will get a ton of money.

**Then get your style to maximum in Lumiose City, You can do this by:**

- completing the Looker Missions
- Enter the Museum a Few times with and without the audio guides
- Ride in the Taxis
- use the Gogoats
- Test your team in the battle institute
- Land perhaps buy 99 Premier balls, (Individually, Buy 1 exit the window, buy another, etc etc.)

Once you have done this you should not only have a ton of money from the Elites, But the Stones should cost you $10,000 a peice so not only will you have them all you will have a ton of money left over.